# Angular: exclude JSON object property from being filtered

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, blob

I am using this http://plnkr.co/edit/U1TOccm3pURetRTUul12?p=preview for searching multiple keywords of objects in json form. Code from plunker:

```
 angular
 .module('demo', [])
 .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.projects = [
  { id: 1, name: 'foo', keywords: 'aa bb cc' },
  { id: 2, name: 'bar', keywords: 'dd ee ff' },
  { id: 3, name: 'qux', lvl1: { lvl2: 'gg hh ii' } },
  { id: 4, name: 'baz', lvl1: { lvl2: { lvl3: 'gg hh ii' } } }
];

$scope.matchProject = function (project) {
  // Match all projects if no terms are entered
  if ($scope.searchText == null) return true;
  // Match project if all terms are matched
  var searchTerms = splitTerms($scope.searchText);
  var projectTerms = walkTerms(project);
  var unmatchedTerms = searchTerms.filter(function (searchTerm) {
    return projectTerms.filter(function (projectTerm) {
      return projectTerm.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1;
    }).length === 0;
  });
  return unmatchedTerms.length === 0;
};

function walkTerms(obj, terms) {
  if (terms == null) {
    terms = [];
  }
  for (var key in obj) {
    // Ignore properties added by Angular
    if (key.startsWith('$$')) continue;
    // Ignore `null`, `undefined` or Array values
    if (obj[key] == null || obj[key].constructor === Array) continue;
    if (obj[key].constructor === Object) {
      walkTerms(obj[key], terms);
      continue;
    }
    if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'string') {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(terms, splitTerms(obj[key]));
      continue;
    }
    // Must be a boolean or number
    terms.push(obj[key].toString());
  }
  return terms;
}

function splitTerms(text) {
  if (text == null) return [];
  return text
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(/\s+/)
    .filter(function (term) {
      return term.length > 0;
    });
}
```

});

`$scope.projects` for me is a list of project objects.

```
$scope.projects = [
  { id: 1, name: 'foo', keywords: 'aa bb cc', image: //BLOB DATA HERE },
  { id: 2, name: 'bar', keywords: 'dd ee ff', image: //BLOB DATA HERE },
  { id: 3, name: 'qux', lvl1: { lvl2: 'gg hh ii' } },
  { id: 4, name: 'baz', lvl1: { lvl2: { lvl3: 'gg hh ii' } } }
 ];
```

I get the object with a SQL query and json_encode it. One of my object keys is a `MEDIUMBLOB`. The ng-repeat filter malfunctions with this property, (dupes and notArray errors).

Is there any way to fix this, e.g. excluding the BLOB property from being searched?  How do I exclude that particular key in the plunker?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off site to simply review your issue. Demos are great, but should only be used to support what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: Beyond that it is not clear in demo or question what specific problem is

Comment: I have edited the post for specifications.

Comment: Without the image property, the filter works fine. But with the MEDIUMBLOB it does not work.

Comment: Create your own custom filter that works on mapped array that removes the properties you don't want to search

Comment: maybe lodash can help you https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4

Comment: There is this line (32 in plunker) `if (key.startsWith('$$')) continue;`. Is there a way to add a similar one liner to exclude the image property? LIke `if (key.startsWith('$image')`? Tried it but the syntax doesnt seem to be correct.